# Real numbers in a compact subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, power-series

Suppose $a$ is a real number, $X$ a non-empty compact subset of the real numbers. Prove that there exists an element $b$ in $X$ closest to $a$ among all elements in $X$.

How would you prove this statement using series? Would you form a power series in $X$ and define the radius of convergence around $a$?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to use series?  Did someone tell you you had to?

Comment: What would be the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I can’t imagine wanting to use series to prove the result; any such proof would be very roundabout.

The easiest way to do it is to define $f:X\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto|x-a|$; $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on a compact set, so by the extreme value theorem there is a point $b\in X$ at which the value of $f$ is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

We will use a sequence, not a series.

Let $h=\inf_{x\in X} |a-x|$.

Let $b_1\in X$. If $|a-b_1|=h$, we are finished.

If $|a-b_1|\gt h$, let $h_1=h+\frac{1}{2}|a-b_1|$. Then there is a $b_2\in X$ such that $|a-b_2|\lt h_1$. If $|a-b_2|=h$ then we are finished.

If $|a-b_2|\gt h$, let $h_2=h+\frac{1}{2}|a-b_2|$. If $|a-b_2|=h$, we are finished. Else continue.

Either at some stage we have $|a-b_n|=h$, in which case we let $b=b_n$, or we obtain an infinite  sequence $b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots$ of elements of $X$ such that $|a-b_n|\lt \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|a-b_1|$. Use Compactness to show that this sequence has a limit $b\in X$, and that $|a-b|=h$.